# CONTROL DATABASE issue when migrating SQL database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm following this [tutorial on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database). I've reached the part where I use the "Data Migration Assistant", but after selecting the target Azure database and clicking "Next", I get the following error:

> An unexpected error occurred.
>   Current principal does not have CONTROL permission on securable AzureDatabaseName of class DATABASE.

I'm using the only user of the Azure SQL server - the server admin, which should have all permissions. I've verified that the user is 'db_owner' by using [IS_ROLEMEMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-rolemember-transact-sql).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue. This seems to be a bug in Azure SQL databases. If you have dots in the database name it does not work. I replaced the dots with slashes and it worked for me.

You do not need to recreate the database. A rename worked fine for me:

1. You have to make sure, that no-one else is using the database!
2. Connect to master table and execute the following script on the Azure SQL Server:

   USE master;
   GO
   ALTER DATABASE [my.database]
   Modify Name = [my-database] ;
   GO

Here is a link on how to rename Azure SQL databases:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rename-a-database

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure to create a firewall rule for your incoming connection. This error can be a bit of a red herring.

Comment: This was my issue! Using an older version of SSMS I wasn't prompted to give the firewall access, but after creating the firewall access I was able to connect with SSMS, and then also with the SQL migration tool

Answer (score 1):

I deleted everything - the database, the sql server, and the resource group. Then I recreated everything using the same names, except the database name - which previously contained dots - and this time the migration tool worked. I guess I just encountered some bug.

Answer (score 0):

if you have dots in target database name, you have to remove or replace the dots in db name.
Like: 'demo.customerdb' to 'demo-customerdb'

You can use Sql Management Studio for db renaming:

1. connect target database server
2. select target database
3. press "F2" key or right click on target database then select
   "Rename"
4. remove dots (.) from the database name and that's it! :)

After then, you can try migration process again from the start.